Low-noise bipolar boost power supply
I am working on a new design, and have a clarifying question.
The circuit is powered from a 5V USB-C connector, and contains a 16-bit DAC (DAC80508) outputting 0-5V, fed into an op-amp circuit to shift it into -5 to +5V.
Since the USB is not always guaranteed to have a stable 5V, and I would also like some head room to not operate the op-amp to rails, I would like a single-IC solution with as few components as possible, that converts 4V-5V into a low-noise, bipolar power supply with output >= ±7V, where +7V (>=100mA) and -7V (>=10mA). The positive output will also be further downregulated to 5V and 3.3V for the DAC and a microcontroller.
I have tried to look for solutions, and most of them have some limitations. For example, LM27762 is a nice, bipolar-output, inductor-less solution that can boost the voltage on positive output, but the negative output is limited to the input voltage magnitude. The only one I could find was TLV61048, so I decided to build a prototype using configuration in application note SLVAEJ3 (Figure 5).




Reference
Qty
MPN
Value
Manufacturer
Package
Datasheet




C1
1
CL05A105KA5NQNC
1uF
Samsung Electro-Mechanics
0402
Link


C2,C4
2
GRM188R61H225KE11D
2.2uF
Murata Electronics
0603
Link


C3
1
CC1206KKX5R8BB106
10uF
YAGEO
1210
Link


D1,D2,D3
3
B120AF-13
B120AF-13
Diodes Incorporated
DO-214AD
Link


L1
1
XAL4030-472
4.7uH
Coilcraft
4.0x4.0x3.1
Link


R1
1
HP03W5F100KT5E
1R
UNI-ROYAL
0603
Link


R2
1
RK73G1ETTP1004F
1M
KOA Speer Elec
0408
Link


R3
1
0402WGF1003TCE
100k
UNI-ROYAL(Uniroyal Elec)
0402
Link


U1
1
TLV61048DBV
TLV61048
Texas Instruments
SOT-23-6
Link



It seems to work fine, but I was wondering if there is a better solution for my application, that would require less components (and preferably no inductor or diodes), and be better in terms of noise characteristics?
Or would you recommend boosting and inverting the voltage in two steps using a multi-ic solution?
I am looking forward to hearing your opinion.
Thank you for help.

There are excellent highly integrated modules available that do this. I would probably not start by designing my own. Well-performing power conversion solutions often need way more components than what you show, so that's why a "chip-scale" module with integrated inductors that works at a very high frequency (often >1MHz) is hard to beat. It takes way smaller volume to filter out 1MHz switching noise than say 100kHz. The "no inductor or diodes" constraint is interesting to say the least: are you low on space? Those aren't exactly specialty components.

Thank you for replying. Would you mind linking some of the integrated modules you have in mind? My priorities are simplicity and low output AC ripple, while minimizing the area on the PCB as much as possible. I understand there are physical limitations, and there might not even exist an inductor/diode-less solution, but I I just wanted to see if someone knows a better solution.

You can always lower the output ripple by boosting to higher than the desired voltage and postregulating with a linear regulator.
